# ImportError with '@tanstack/react-virtual' module: 'useVirtualizer' not exported?

Tags: reactjs, tanstack, tanstackreact-query

I'm encountering an issue while using the @tanstack/react-virtual library in my React project. According to the documentation, I should be able to import and use the useVirtualizer function from this module. However, when I try to import it as shown below:

import { useVirtualizer } from "@tanstack/react-virtual";

I receive the following error message:

"'@tanstack/react-virtual' has no exported member named 'useVirtualizer'. Did you mean 'useVirtual'?"

It seems that the useVirtualizer function is not being recognized as an exported member of the module. I have double-checked the documentation and my code, and everything seems to be in order. Could someone help me understand why I'm encountering this error and how I can resolve it?

React version: 18.2
Node.js version: 20.3
Tanstack/react-virtual: 3.0.0-alpha.0

import { useVirtualizer } from "@tanstack/react-virtual";

I expected this import statement to work without any issues and for me to be able to use the useVirtualizer function in my React component. However, instead of the expected behavior, I encountered the following error message:

"'@tanstack/react-virtual' has no exported member named 'useVirtualizer'. Did you mean 'useVirtual'?"

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of [3.0.0-alpha.0](https://github.com/TanStack/virtual/blob/v3.0.0-alpha.0/packages/react-virtual/src/index.tsx), you will see that the `useVirtualizer` doesn't exist in there.

Switch to `3.0.0-beta.60` to use `useVirtualizer` or review other package versions https://github.com/TanStack/virtual/tags